# Issue in formatting Date in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, swift4.2, dateformatter

I am having a Issue in formatting Date in swift 4
The time HH:mm:ss getting wrong data, when formatting the source code is provided below.

```
    let dateFormatter : DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a
    let date = Date()
    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

I am getting result as  : 11-Aug-2020 12:01:23 PM

If i am trying to convert the result of string date to date

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a" 
    let serverDate: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
```

I am getting result as : 2020-08-11 06:31:39 +0000

Expected must be : 2020-08-11 12:01:23 +0000 
But i am getting result as : 2020-08-11 06:31:39 +0000

If anyone know the solution, please give me a solution.

Comment: `HH` with `a`, that's a strange format. Are you in a Timezone where you have 5h30 diff with UTC, like let's say, India ? Because that's my strongest suspicion.

Comment: Yea I am from india, is there any solution for that @Larme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HH:mm:ss` gives you the time in 24 hour format, so `a` doesn't make sense inside the format. Or you can use `hh:mm:ss a`.

`Date()` gives you the time in `UTC`. You need to provide the timezone information to get the date in your timezone.

```
    let date = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = .current
    let localDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    
    print(localDate)
```

`localDate` will give you the date in your current timezone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your format. If you try with dateFormat = `"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`, you will get expected results. Also, I recommend you to set **locale** and **timezone**. For example:

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
let date = Date()
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

let serverDate: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
```